# Mix blend mode renders incorrectly in safari

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I came across this issue in safari where using `mix-blend-mode: color;` doesn't work correctly. I tested other blend modes which work fine. Strangely despite this seeming like very common issue, I didn't find any `color` blend mode specific discussion. Any ideas on how to fix this? I tried adding `#overlay` inside `#image` div but getting same results.

```css
#image{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1070/800/600.jpg?hmac=TQrM01Rpkjic5HhbuMrBGEdrR3mjDSyubaTTRmkMqVU);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#overlay{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(178,151,4,0.75) 0%, rgba(43,48,59,1) 100%);
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/css-mixblendmode Safari as of current version does not support the color blend mode (among others).

So you might not be able to fix this at all, with CSS. 

Any reasons why you cant apply the graphical effect on the image with a program before?

Comment: Unfortunately can't use edited images due to complexity but thanks for responding, it helped.